# Gear for Pandaria

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I play as a Holy/Shadow Priest (for questing) and I'm currently level 85.

How can I improve my gear quickly while increasing my item level sufficiently to unlock the dungeons in Pandaria?

Also, how is your average gear level defined?

Comment: More then a year ago since i played wow, but the gear is defined using ItemLevels. It takes the average of that item level. Now the easyest thing you can do is find stuff with high itemlevels. Equip, queue join, then reequip the lower itemlevels with the correct stats.

Comment: @Lyrion Ive quited wow 3 years ago, so years got a lot of questions to reunderstand all the changes.

Comment: Normally if you hover over your gear it should say something as in Itemlevel 512 or something like that. Could be it was an addon... it has been ages.

Comment: @Lyrion that was probably gear/playerscore - item levels weren't exposed in the interface until Cataclysm and have only just started reaching item levels of 500+ in Pandaria

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're planning on healing your way through these instances, around level 87-88 there the amount of spirit you need to keep your mana pool full starts to go up by quite a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get a lot of gear through the initial stages of questing that will increase your item level, this is the quickest 'cheap' way to achieve the required item level to enter these dungeons. The quickest 'overall' method of getting higher level gear would be through using the auction house, although other options include levelling the tailoring profession and using that to create cloth gear for questing/dungeons.

Depending on the gear that you had in Cataclysm, you should be able to enter the initial Temple of the Jade Serpent and Stormstout Brewery instances straight away but if you do not meet the requirement for these then the upgrades you get from the initial quest chain in Jade Forest should dramatically increase your item level quite quickly.

Average item level is calculated by taking the item level of each item you have equipped and dividing it by the number of equipment slots excluding the tabard and shirt slots. In the instance of using a two handed weapon, the off hand weapon slot is not included in the calculation. However, in the instance where you have a 'required' slot empty (ie: head slot or shoulder slot) this slot is still included in the calculation but with an item level of 0 when summing up the item level of that slot. This means that a fully equipped character using two one hand weapons has sixteen item slots while a character using a two hand weapon has fifteen item slots.

Comment: Do trinkets include in this calculation of average itemlevel?

Comment: Yes trinkets are included in the item level calculation - every slot except for Shirt and Tabard are used in the calculation, with the additional exception of the off hand slot if you're using a two hand weapon

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way in my opinion is to visit a trader for adventuring goods. In Jade Forest that would be [Silkweaver Rui](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=61598) for alliance and [Singegruff](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=56705) for horde. They sell items of level 372 for all specs and slots.